# On obfuscation size of jar increased

Tags: java, proguard

I have device here using Tc65i processor and to run my jar in it in a compressed manner I need to obfusicate the on building the jar. I first exported my jar normally the size of my jar was 397KB but after obfusication the size increased to 520KB. The obfusication is done using proguard in eclipse. The same project running on another machine on exporting the jar via obfusication gives a 183KB file. The configuration in prefernces and the project properties seem to be the same. What might be the reason behind this problem?

Comment: You're stating something here that you observed. That could be the start of your question - *but you haven't included any actual questions*. What is it that you want to know?

Comment: Jar files are compressed, so after obfuscation the compression ratio may have changed (granted the difference is rather big). Question is mainly what happened to the (uncompressed) size of the class files inside the jar?